# express middleware to modify requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, w2ui

i currently have a running server using nodejs, mongo, express and W2UI for the front end.
W2ui requests come in an a record array that has all the parameters
 record[name]:foo
i want to write a middleware that edits requests and changes them before they reach the route.

Answer (score 24):

You can create your own middleware to manipulate the request. I've created a middleware that adds current server time to the request like this

```
var addDate = function(req, res, next) {
  req.body.date = new Date();
  next();
}
```

Now, I can use this middleware for all requests like this:

```
app.use(addDate);
```

or to a spesific route like this

```
app.get('/', addDate, function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

The response from the get request will be

```
{
  "date": "2017-01-31T11:46:37.003Z"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in http.js, create a function to modify request in a way you want and then give it in order array like below : -

```
order: [
  'startRequestTimer',
  'cookieParser',
  'session',
  'bodyParser',
  'xframe',
  'handleBodyParserError',
  '**myRequestLogger**',
  'compress',
  'methodOverride',
  // 'poweredBy',
  '$custom',
  'router',
  'ravenRequestHandler',
  'ravenErrorHandler',
  'www',
  'favicon',
  '404',
  '500'
],
```

myrequestLogger is a function to log the request here.